# Rollback to a specfic Migration in FluentMigrator

Tags: c#, sql-server, fluent-nhibernate, fluent, fluent-migrator

Suppose I have crated a three Table using FluentMigrator and gave them version Number 1, 2, 3 respectively. Now Is there any way to rollback till version 2. I mean After rollback I should have Table 1 and 2 but not 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a batch file I use with the command line runner tool

```
@echo off
if "%1" == "rollback" goto rollback
if "%1" == "" goto migrate
if "%1" == "version" goto version
if "%1" == "down" goto down
goto error

:migrate
migrate -db SqlServer2014 -connection "Server=[YOUR CONNECTTION STRING]" -assembly "[YOUR MIGRATION ASSEMBLY]"
goto done

:rollback
migrate -db SqlServer2014 -connection "Server=[YOUR CONNECTTION STRING]" -assembly "[YOUR MIGRATION ASSEMBLY]" -task rollback:all
goto done

:version
migrate -db SqlServer2014 -version "%2" -connection "Server=[YOUR CONNECTTION STRING]" -assembly "[YOUR MIGRATION ASSEMBLY]"
goto done

:down
migrate -db SqlServer2014 -version %2 -connection "Server=[YOUR CONNECTTION STRING]" -assembly "[YOUR MIGRATION ASSEMBLY]" -task rollback:toversion

:error
echo "No valid command"

:done
echo "Completed"
```

Then you would use the forth option: down as follows

1. Open a Cmd in the directory the batch file exists, the command line runner dlls and the migration assembly dll need to exist in that directory
2. Run the following [Batch File Name].bat down [Version YOU WANT TO ROLLBACK TO: i.e., Migration you want as your last one]

So in your example that would be "down 2", which will rollback 3 and you would keep 1 and 2.

More about [Command Line Runner](https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator/wiki/Command-Line-Runner-Options)

Answer (score 0):

Use the below command to down migrate to version 2. The below command will execute the down method of all the files which has migration number greater than 2.

```
migrate --conn "<Your Connection String>" --provider sqlserver --assembly "<Dll path of the Migration files assembly>" --task migrate:down --version 2
```